# Create a function from other function but with prefilled arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to create a function as equal to another function but with pregiven arguments.
Something like

```
function f(x){
  return x
}
var f2 = //f(2);
console.log(f2()); //Should print 2
```

I know this is somewhat possible in OcamL, so I wonder if I can do it in JS.
Another way would be to do

```
var f2 = function(){f(2)};
f2();
```

But I don't know how illegal that is, and if I should fear prison or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1** - Create a wrapper function that returns the result of calling `f()` with `2`.

```js
function f(x){
  return x
}

var f2 = () => f(2);

console.log(f2()); //Should print 2
```

**Option 2** - use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) with [prepended arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Parameters):

```js
function f(x){
  return x
}

var f2 = f.bind(null, 2);

console.log(f2()); //Should print 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make `f2` a function that **calls** `f` with whatever you want then **returns** the result of that call to `f`:

```
var f2 = function() {
    return f(2);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a function within the function.

```js
function f(x)
{
  return function() {
    return x;
  };
}

var f2 = f(2),
    f3 = f(3),
    f4 = f(4);

console.log("f2: " + f2());
console.log("f3: " + f3());
console.log("f4: " + f4());
```